# Problem of different spaces between subscripts and letters in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, subscripts, kerning

In math mode, the spaces between subscripts and letters are not always the same, but depending on the preceding letters!

See e.g. (different colours indicate different spaces)[image]

Is it the feature of packages `{amssymb}` `{amsmath}` or ....

Equations using `{newtxmath}` math font:

```
    \begin{equation}
    \left.
    \begin{array} {c}
    \displaystyle \frac{\partial\epsilon_f}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot (\epsilon_f \boldsymbol{u}_f) = 0 \\
    \displaystyle \frac{\partial  (\rho_f \epsilon_f \boldsymbol{u}_f)}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot (\rho_f \epsilon_f \boldsymbol{u}_f \boldsymbol{u}_f) = -\epsilon_f \nabla p + \mu \nabla^2(\epsilon_f \boldsymbol{u}_f) + \boldsymbol{f}_b
    \end{array}
    \right\}
    \end{equation}
```

Is there any global setting/solution for this issue, i.e. to adjust the spacing automatically depending on the letters and subscripts?

**EDIT**: put `{bm}` package after `amsmath` and `font` packages will significantly improve the spacing.

Comment: Since you are using `newtxmath` I'd like to recommend the `mtpro2` package, whose `lite` version is free. it has a package option `subscriptcorrection`, which deals exactly with the kind of problem you have.

Comment: I just had a look at the `Readme` pf `mtpro2` package. Some of the mathematical symbols and operators seem to be improved a lot. Does the free version `lite` provide these features?

Comment: Which stuff is available or not can be checked in the [manual](ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/fonts/mtp2lite/texmf/doc/fonts/mtpro2/mtpro2.pdf).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some testing I found that loading `\usepackage{bm}` significantly improves the spacing. As **David** points out in the comment, the kerning is possible, but grouping plays a role here. Obviously his package `bm` does better job on `\boldsymbol` than `amsmath`. *Just remember to load `bm` after `amsmath` and after your font packages!*

Comment: I know `\!` produces a negative thin space in math mode, but I was wondering, is there a versatile solution to adjust the spacing automatically to a certain value between subscript and letter?

Comment: TeX does use per-character kerning information of subscripts compare `$P_1  P{}_1$` where the subscript is pulled in for `P` in the first case but not in the second.

Comment: @tohecz Thanks, I tried `bm` package before, the spacing looks even. However, the bold math font will become `cm` font. Anyway, it's a good solution for now.

Comment: @KOF bm will use the fonts that are loaded at the point the package is loaded so if boldmath version is already set up before bm is loaded then it shouldn't use cm fonts.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, now it works like charm when putting `bm` package after the `font` package!

Answer (score 6):

It is a feature of the font and TeX's font parameters.

While TeX does have some fontdimen parameters which control subscript positioning the main controller here is the font metrics where Tex is using the kerning information to pull (or not) subscripts under italic sloped base. However the visual gap also depends on which pixels are black compared to the specified rectangular bounding box of the glyph, and TeX has no knowledge of that at all.

Comment: if you compare the results of `\[ f_\epsilon \boldsymbol{f}_\epsilon \]` you will find that the position of the subscript is quite different. one might suspect that the metrics of `cmmi` and `cmmib` aren't equivalent, but comparison of the two (via `.pl` files) shows that not to be the case.  that implies that the definition via `\boldsymbol` must be faulty, and indeed, `\[ \text{\textit{\textbf{f}}}_\epsilon \]` gives the same result as using `\boldsymbol`.  i'll add this to our problems list.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The metrics are not used if you use boldsymbol as that starts an hbox (4 actually) and does a new math list in each in a \mathchoice so there is no possibility of getting kern information between the characters it's like \hbox{f}\hbox{f}\hbox{i} has no ligature. That's why \bm goes to some effort to get bold without doing that

Comment: which is why `\boldsymbol` really needs to be looked at.  thanks for the pointer.  there was already a request on our list to consider how `bm` was implemented to see if it could lead to any improvements in `amsmath`; since it was suggested by frank mittelbach, it's kind of an imperative, when `amsmath` finally gets scheduled for overhaul, but now that there's a good bad example, it gets upgraded from a request to a bug.